# Quantmod - Chop data and constructing matrix of return series

Tags: r, quantmod

I am having trouble with my R assignment I am working on this semester.

Here is the part that I am tasked with doing that I am confused about:

iv. Download 3 month TBill rate from Fred for the same sample period 01/01/1993 to 12/31/2013.

- Useful Hints: You may have to chop the data to match the sample period.

v. Construct a matrix of return series combining Stock, S&P500, and TBill for the sample period.

Useful Hints:

- Note that the rownames for the TBill may not match with the other two return series, as the dates do not match, although the month and year matches
- You have to construct the row names for each of the series as Year – Month format (e.g. 1993-01) or delete the rownames from T-bill before you can combine all three series into one Return matrix.
- You have to convert the Return matrix to a dataframe before you use the lm() function.

I tried this below like I have used getSymbols before for SPY and AAPL but it pulls an entire data set rather than the specific date range. How can I chop the data so it fits the desired date range?

```
getSymbols('TB3MS', src = 'FRED', from = "1993-01-01", to = "2013-12-31")
```

Next, how would I go about constructing the matrix of return series combining all of the stocks? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Filtering an xts object: see examples in the xts documentation `?xts`.

```
# filter 1993 until 2013
TB3MS["1993/2013"]
```

But these dates are of, because tbills are at the first day of the month, the stock dates are the last day of the month. With the `coredata` you can extract the tbill data and stick it into the other timeseries if the rows match.

Taking the data example from your previous question, you could do something like this (and I'm creating more steps than needed, you could combine a few statements into one):

```
# create monthly returns of the spy data and give the column a better name than monthly.returns
spy_returns <- monthlyReturn(SPY)
colnames(spy_returns) <- "SPY_returns"

# filter the tbill data
TB3MS_1993_2013 <- TB3MS["1993/2013"]

# add tbill data to spy data
spy_returns$TB3MS <- coredata(TB3MS_1993_2013)
```

Merging xts objects can just be done with `merge`. They will be merged on the dates.

`merge(spy_returns, aapl_returns)` would combine these two. If you have a lot of tickers, use `Reduce` (check help and SO on how to use `Reduce` with `merge`) but better would be to use the tidyquant package if allowed.

Comment: So if I merge AAPL returns and SPY returns with merge and then add the tbill data, wouldn't that still be an xts? How would I convert the final combined matrix into a data frame so I can use the lm() function?

Comment: To transform an xts into a data.frame just do something like this: `data.frame(date = index(AAPL), coredata(AAPL))`